# How to Insert data into one table from different UI?

Tags: php, sql

In my android app, There is 3 type of UI. In backend I have used PHP for calling web service in android. In my case, There is one table namely registration detail which have column namely first name, last name, email, password, gender, city, country etc. Now, I create php web service for Insert 3 field namely first name, last name or email. It is inserted successfully in database. Now for password , birthdate gender I have fired Update query on null column then it is inserted successfully but my problem is that when table have any of null field then update that null field with new inserted record. I don't know my concept is right or wrong any one please correct me or guide me.

Php code

```
 public function StoreInfo($firstname, $lastname, $email)
 {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ibeInsert(firstname,lastname,email) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname,$lastname,$email);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    if($result)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT firstname,lastname,email FROM ibeInsert WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($token2,$token3,$token4);
        while( $stmt->fetch() )
        {
            $user["firstname"]=$token2;
            $user["lastname"]=$token3;
            $user["email"]=$token4;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling function in php file:

```
  <?php

  require_once 'update_user_info.php';
  $db = new update_user_info();

  $response = array("error" => FALSE);

   if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) &&      isset($_POST['email']))
 {
// receiving the post params
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $lastname =$_POST['lastname'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
    // create a new user
    $user = $db->StoreSocialInfo($firstname,$lastname,$email);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["user"]["firstname"] = $user["firstname"];
        $response["user"]["lastname"]=$user["lastname"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        echo json_encode($response);
       }   
        else 
        {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
        }

 } else {
  $response["error"] = TRUE;
  $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters   (Firstname,lastname,email) is missing!";
     echo json_encode($response);
 }
  ?>
```

Now My second Part (GENDER,COUNTRY,CITY)

```
Update query fired on same table

 public function StoreInfoTo($gender,$country,$city)
  {

   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE ibeInsert SET gender=?,country=?,city=? WHERE id=? OR gender IS NULL OR country IS NULL OR city IS NULL");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $gender, $country, $city,$id);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
     if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT gender, country,city,id FROM ibeInsert");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt-> bind_result($token2,$token3,$token4,$token1);
        while ( $stmt-> fetch() ) {
           $user["gender"] = $token2;
           $user["country"]=$token3;
           $user["city"] = $token4;
           $user["id"]=$token1;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

}
```

In database, When I inserted new record in to database then last inserted record is updated in gender country city like that:

id:1 name:riche lastname:shah gender:female, country:India city:Mumbai
id:2 name:xyz   lastname:pos  gender:female, country:India city:Mumbai

last 3 column is updated when new record inserted into database.

Comment: what is your problem exactly, is it like always last inserted record is updated ?

Comment: Yes similar that, Only update last three column gender, country city. If you don't mind can you please tell me my concept of insertion is right or wrong? @user7417866

Comment: see my ans for, hope it clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the prob is in your update query,

```
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE ibeInsert SET gender=?,country=?,city=? WHERE id=? OR gender IS NULL OR country IS NULL OR city IS NULL");
```

I cannot see your are passing ID into your update function

```
public function StoreInfoTo($gender,$country,$city)
```

since you are using OR condition into where clause you will be getting last inserted values always null and whenever you will fire update it will fetch these null values and update the same.

You should not use null values into your where clause instead search by ID or any index values to identify records.

also firing update on NULL values is not recommended as your table may have multiple null values and update will replace all null values unless you use AND with identity index of your table.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you give an example please I am confused. @user7417866

Comment: I'm not php guy, all I can tell you is instead of OR use AND into your update query and fetch ID before you fire update query and pass the same ID for update..

Comment: When I pass Id into update query then new record is inserted but not in last inserted id I want insert record into last inserted record that's why I will use Update query. @user7417866